# Evaluate Formal tools

Tags: verification, formal-verification

What are all the factors one should consider in order to compare 3 formal verification tools? 
Eg: Jaspergold, Onespin, Incisive.

From my little research, Jaspergold comes on top. But i want to do it myself on a project.

I have noted down some points such as
1.Supported languages(vhdl, sv, verilog, sva, psl,etc)
2.GUI 
3.Capability(how much big design can they handle)
4.Number of Evaluation cycles
5.Performance(How fast they find proof or counter example)

With what other features can i extend this list?

Thanks!